# Visual Studio 2013 Project Template Customization

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, project-template

I'd like to customize the UnitTest project template for Visual Studio 2013: We use Moq very often in UnitTest projects, hence I think it should be automatically referenced.

In `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplates\CSharp\Test\1033\UnitTestProject`, I edited `UnitTestProject.csproj` by adding a reference section and an ItemGroup:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <None Include="packages.config" />
</ItemGroup>
...
<Reference Include="Moq, Version=4.2.1510.2205, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=69f491c39445e920, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\Moq.4.2.1510.2205\lib\net40\Moq.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
```

Then I added the file packages.config to that folder, and edited `UnitTestProject.vstemplate` by adding

```
<ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="false" TargetFileName="packages.config">packages.config</ProjectItem>
```

to the Project section.

But when I create a new UnitTest project, I get the error message

```
The file packages.config could not be found within the project templates. Continuing to run, but the resulting project may not build properly.
```

After clicking OK, another error message follows:

```
Unable to copy the file 'packages.config' from the project template to the project. Cannot find file "(%TEMP%\some folder)\packages.config'.
```

How can that be solved?

Answer (score 0):

Beyond changing the template in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplates`, I had to replace it also in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplatesCache`. Next, I had to look into `%AppData%\C:\Users\bernhard.hiller\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\ProjectTemplatesCache` and delete the zip-file for the template.

Now the `packages.config` file gets copied when I add a new Unit Test Project manually. But when using the "Unit Test Generator" (see https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/45208924-e7b0-45df-8cff-165b505a38d7), this file is missing while all other changes to the project (post build actions, references, ...) are applied.